# User input number lies in which two numbers among the array

Tags: python

So, if 
`a=[1 , 2.3 , 5.5 , 6 , 3.2 , 4.8]` and user inputs `x = 2.2` - I should get output like `(1 , 2.3)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
l = [1 , 2.3 , 5.5 , 6 , 3.2 , 4.8]
n = float(input())
l.append(n)
l.sort()
idx = l.index(n)
print('(',l[idx-1],',',l[idx+1],')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array isn't sorted, so you could have multiple answers.
Think of it as a graph that can go up and down, and your input is drawing a horizontal line.
Which segments of the graph intersect that line.

```
>>> a = [1, 2.3, 5.5, 6, 3.2, 4.8]

>>> def sections(val, samples):
...     for (i, j) in zip(samples[:-1], samples[1:]):
...         if i <= val <= j:
...             yield (i, j)

>>> n = float(input('enter number: '))
2.2
>>> list(sections(n, a))
[(1, 2.3)]
```

This way multiple intersection points will also work:

```
>>> list(sections(4, a))
[(2.3, 5.5), (3.2, 4.8)]
```

Or, if you prefer a one-liner:

```
>>> [x for x in map(lambda i: (a[i], a[i+1]) if (a[i] <= n <= a[i+1]) else None, range(len(a)-1)) if x]
[(1, 2.3)]
```